# setString and setNString in postgresqljdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

The question specifically referring to Postgresqljdbc community is why does the `setNString` method throws `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` exception?

I know Postgres handles it through varchar so setString is sufficient but for use case which I have is I need setNString and so so many others might be.
I have a JdbcWriter class intended to be general.

For Handling nvarchar  I have specified if the data is Unicode refers to nString else string so in case of postgres I have specified another check to verify the db product from the connection.

If the implementation of the nString was provided as calling the setString in it as simple; what was the design restriction on that for Postgresql.

Comment: If you look at the list of [PostgreSQL Data Types / Character Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/datatype-character.html) it should be clear that you get a not supported exception because postgres doesn't have nchar or nvarchar.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I think the JDBC driver could simply forward `setNString()` to `setString()` rather than throwing an exception. But then I don't know if the JDBC specs require anything special for setNString

Comment: I think this question is better suited to be asked on the [Postgres JDBC mailing list](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/community/mailinglist.html)

Comment: sure I will do that too. The reason for asking is to understand the restriction, whereas there might be scenarios like the one I have mentioned where migration would require code changes for an application.